# Simply traditional foreach to Linq ForEach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a list of strings like:

```
abcd@domain.com
efgh@domain.com
ijkl@domain.com;mnop@domain.com;qrst@domain.com
uvwx@domain.com
yz@domain.com
```

I would like to want it as:

```
abcd@domain.com
efgh@domain.com
ijkl@domain.com
mnop@domain.com
qrst@domain.com
uvwx@domain.com
yz@domain.com
```

So I wrote the code below and it works as expected.

```
foreach (var email in emailAddressesOnRequest)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && email.Contains(';'))
    {
        emailAddressesOnRequest.AddRange(email.Split(';').ToList());
        emailAddressesOnRequest.Remove(email);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to simply it to LINQ ForEach?

Comment: `List.ForEach` is not LINQ, it's a method that existed already before LINQ.

Comment: How to make it LINQ ForEach then?

Comment: Have you noticed that your `foreach` throws an exception if you modify the list during enumeration? You could fix it by using: `foreach (var email in emailAddressesOnRequest.ToList()){...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is to iterate through the collection and for each item to return an item of a different kind. For that use `Select`.

Because in your case you possibly want to return from each item a collection of items, and don't want to have them in nested collections use `SelectMany` on the result of the `Split(';')` method.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>
{
    "abcd@domain.com",
    "efgh@domain.com",
    null,
    "ijkl@domain.com; mnop @domain.com; qrst @domain.com",
    "uvwx@domain.com",
    "yz@domain.com"
};

var result = values.Where(value => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                   .SelectMany(value => value.Split(';')).ToList();
```

And in query syntax:

```
var result = (from value in values
             where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
             from email in value.Split(';')
             select email).ToList();
```

Comment: OP uses `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, so maybe it can be null. Apart from that nice and simple solution.

Comment: better would be to omit null values, he doesn't remove them from the list either. But i guess it's actually not needed at all if the list cannot contain nulls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - What do you mean?

Comment: the `Where` removes them, OP's `foreach` just skips those values so they remain in the list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Ahh ok ya :) thought I missed something

Comment: @Ehsan - Thanks for fixing the typo and adding the documentation for the Select :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from line in emailAddressesOnRequest
            where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
            from email in line.Split(';')
            select email;
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me a lot to understand ling was [The standard LINQ operators](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx)

If you split each string into substrings by semicolon, you get a collection of string sequences, or an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`

The `IEnumareable` extension function to convert them to an `IEnumerable<string>` is `Enumerable.SelectMany`. When iterating over a `SelectMany` it is like you do a nested foreach:

```
List<string[]> listOfStringArrays = ...
List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
foreach (string[] stringArray in listOfStringArrays)
{
     foreach (string str in stringArray)
     {
         outputList.Add(str);
     }
}
```

In your example the inner foreach is done using `AddRange`.

Using `Select` and `Split` you convert your collection of strings to a sequence of string sequences. `SelectMany` will make it a sequence of strings:

```
IEnumerable<string> myInputStrings = ...
IEnumerable<string> outputStrings = inputStrings
    .Select(inputString => inputString.Split(';'))
    .SelectMany(splitResult => splitResult);
```

The Select will take each of the inputStrings, and split them by semicolon. The output is a string array, which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, even if your input didn't have a semicolon.

The `SelectMany` concatenates every string sequence of you sequence of string sequences. The result is one sequence of strings.

To convert to array or list use `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.